# Question mark in Network Manager Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: network-manager, 17.10, ethernet

I use ethernet with my laptop becuase of certain reasons. Every so often the ethernet turns into a question mark and there is no internet until i reboot.

Comment: No need to apologize. The vast majority of "computerized" mankind uses the ethernet.  ;-)

Comment: So true. i have my wifi card disabled because it's not strong enough. I have dd-wrt router in Client-Bridge mode used for ethernet and my internet is like a billion times faster now.